# CSS background shrink/expand issue when browser is resized

Tags: html, css, background-image

When I resize the browser (window) it shrinks the top background images (yellow squares) and causes a 1px break in the layout (the red squares show the area with the problem). I tried to force the size to always be the same for the top background images by setting width to 50px. The rest of the background is the repeated-x content_bg_sliver.gif image that I show by using a purple square. Any suggestions?

Thanks,
partizan

P.S: Please see attached images that shows the problem within the red squares.

```
<!-- HTML CODE Starts -->
<div id="top-navigation-container-inner"> 
  <div id="top-nav-left-background"><!-- The left background appended to the top     main navigation --></div>
  <div id="top-nav-right-background"><!-- The right background appended to the top main navigation --></div>
</div> 

<div id="main-body-container">
   <div id="main-body-container-inner">
        main content goes here....
   </div> 
</div> 

<!-- HTML CODE Ends -->



/* CSS Code Starts */
#top-navigation-container-inner {
background: #FFF; 
height: 160px; 
float: none;
font: 14px Arial;
position: relative; 
}

#top-nav-left-background, #top-nav-right-background {
    height: 370px; 
    position: relative; 
    top: 0; 
    width: 50px; 
}

#top-nav-left-background {
    background: url('../images/top_nav_left_background.gif') left bottom no-repeat; 
    float: left;  
    margin-left: -50px;   
}

#top-nav-right-background {
    background: url('../images/top_nav_right_background.gif') right bottom no-repeat;
    float: right;  
    margin-right: -50px;   
}

#main-body-container{
background: aqua url('../images/content_bg_sliver.gif') center repeat-y; 
float:none;
overflow:hidden;  
width: 100%;   
height: 400px;  
}

/*  End CSS Code */
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: hi - do you have a url to view?

Comment: No, sorry I don't. It's in development. May be you can suggest a website where I can export my code to and make it available online?

Comment: Try jsFiddle.net or jsBin.com.

Comment: Sorry, I won't be able to post the code there.

Comment: how come your are doing the left and right sides as 2 backgrounds? scrap these and do the following:

say your site is 800px wide you would create your repeat-y graphic 800x1px with your left and right shadow in the right places then repeat-y it down your main layout - this will give you the shadow edges you want - keep code down and is much better than the way you are doing it now

Comment: just putting together an example for you right now - will post url in few mins!

Comment: Thanks guys for your suggestions, but all of them assume that the background is the same from top to bottom, which is not true. As you can see on my screen capture the top becomes very thin (it fades out). Because of that I needed to use two background images.

Answer (score 0):

try looking at this and see if this is what your after and if you think it's a better way to go about it!

http://drupalgeeks.co.uk/example/